# kubectl create secret command to identify if the created secret is existing or not existing then if it is existing it will not create secret

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

I want to use the kubectl create secret command to identify if the created secret is existing or not existing then if it is existing it will not create the existing secret.

currently I have this command:

`kubectl create secret generic test-key --dry-run=client --output=name >/dev/null 2>&1 || echo "Secret does not exist, creating secret." && kubectl create secret generic test-key --from-literal=testkey="mysecret"`

I tried running this command but I'm getting this error message saying **"error: failed to create secret secrets "test-key" already exists"**

Comment: `kubectl apply` can figure this out on its own, if you write a Secret YAML file (which can be committed to source control).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did resolve this issue by using this command below:

`kubectl create secret generic my-test-key --from-file=/home/mac/testing/test-key --dry-run=client -o yaml | kubectl apply -f -`

this command overwrite the existing secret. this resolve my issue as this will overwrite my created secret previously.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
kubectl get secret $SECRET_NAME >/dev/null 2>&1 || kubectl create secret generic $SECRET_NAME --from-literal=key=value
```

It will create a secret if it doesn't exist. If it exists, do nothing.

Comment: tried this command on my machine to test but still having the error message "error: failed to create secret secrets "test-key" already exists"

Comment: can you share `kubectl get secrets` output?

Comment: this is the output message  "error: failed to create secret secrets "test-key" already exists"

Comment: i need you run `kubectl get secrets` command, not `kubectl create secret`

Comment: resolved this by using this command ``kubectl create secret generic my-test-key --from-file=/home/mac/testing/test-key --dry-run=client -o yaml | kubectl apply -f -``